# Angularjs - highchairs in directive

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

When I test the doughnut chart with jQuery (no angular), my chart works well ([See my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1ZhpXAdfSOcCsomJ7uOC?p=preview)). However, when I put it in angular directive, nothing shows up. I use templateUrl here because the actual template is much more complicated than that.

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div my-chart></div>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('myChart', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: 'true',
        templateUrl: 'my-chart.html',
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, element) {

            var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'chart_1',
                    type: 'pie',
                    height: 200,
                },
                colors: ['#FF0F00', '#FBAF34', '#00cc00'],
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                exporting: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                tooltip: {
                    //enabled: false,
                    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br><table>',
                    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{point-color}">{point.name}: </td>' + '<td style="text-align: right">{point.y} %</td></tr>',
                    footerFormat: '</table>'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        point: {
                            events: {
                                click: function () {
                                    alert('Site name: ' + this.series.name + ', severity: ' + this.name + " value: " + this.y);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    pie: {
                        innerSize: 120,
                        // disable data label
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: "Site 1",
                    data: [
                        {name: "Critical", y: 56.33},
                        {name: "Warning", y: 24.03},
                        {name: "Ok", y: 10.38}
                    ]
                }]
            });
        }
    };
  });
```

**my-chart.html**

```
<div id="chart_1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked over your code, everything looked sound. You did not provide a plunker for the latest code (with directive), so I created one for you! I imagine you did not add the JQuery script because Angular has some built in. As it is is not perfect at the moment, some items are left out, HighChart requires some additional pieces. What it requires specifically I'm not sure. The console log shows multiple errors without JQuery being added. Hopefully items missing from JQuery in Angular will be added soon!

http://plnkr.co/edit/u6I1zr?p=preview

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

<body>
  <div my-chart></div>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs uses a subset of JQuery which is known as "jQuery lite" or "jqLite".jqLite implements only the most commonly needed functionality so if you want the enhanced functionality you need to load jquery library before angularjs

below is the link for the docs:-

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element